# Retrieve cookie from other directory

Tags: php, jquery, cookies, jquery-plugins

I have set **cookie** with the jQuery Cookied plugin and when I try to access it with the PHP, then it is not working.

Cookie has been set with the following code :

```
$.cookie("_culture", culture, { expires: 365, path: '/' });
```

And I tried to get it with `$_COOKIE['_culture']` but it is **not working**.

I am not able to find the reason. **But I think its DIRECTORY RELATED issue**.Because if I try to get it through the same directory, then it works perfectly.

But when I tried it from other directory, then it is not working.

How can I make it accessible in all the directories ?

(I checked cookies and the cookie what I want to retrieve is present there.)

Answer (score 0):

You should add a domain so it will be accessible from your root & subdirectories.

```
$.cookie('_culture', culture, { expires: 365, path: '/', domain: 'example.com' });
```

Comment: Currently I am making it in localhost so when I try to add `domain: '0.0.0.0/directory'` then it stops adding cookie and without adding domain, it works fine.

Comment: @Twix, try to change the domain to `domain: 'localhost'`

Comment: I am using it with the port as well ... Will it okay if I only add localhost or do I need to add port number as well ?

Comment: @Twix I believe it will work without the port and you should try both if the first one does not work.

Comment: Just tried .. But not working .. What might be the issue in my case ?